# How To Access 'List<Map<String, Object>>' Elements In Dart?

Tags: dart

How Can I Print 'White' Element From The Given Code ?

```
void main() {
   var a = [
    {
      'question': "Which is your favourite colour ?",
      'answer': ['Blue', 'White', 'Black', 'Pink']
    }
  ];
  print(`Enter Code Here`);
}
```

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck? What have you read on json so far, how familiar are you with serialization. How portable does this solution have to be, do you want a hacky one-line that will do exactly as you asked, or do you want an explanation how to deserialize json in production code?

Comment: Your code does not compile. A pretty good indicator is that the syntax coloring is messed up here already. Please fix your code.

Comment: Check It Again Now !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the hacky, answer that will solve you immediate problem is

```
void main() {
   var a = [
    {
      'question': "Which is your favourite colour ?",
      'answer': ['Blue', 'White', 'Black', 'Pink']
    }
  ];
  print((a[0]['answer'] as Iterable).elementAt(1));
}
```

However, since you probably not only have this very specific problem to solve, you may want to look into [json serialization techniques](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json).